# How to float list view just below the Edit text (search Box) and over the the others views like Button

Tags: android

I wanna show the List like as shown in the image.Searched a lot on Google but did not get the answer. Please help... [Example Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlJkl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the AutoCompleteTextView to show suggestions under edittext

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_auto_complete.htm

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <AutoCompleteTextView
          android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:ems="10"
          android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
          android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
          android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView"
          android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
          android:hint="AutoComplete TextView">
          <requestFocus />

   </AutoCompleteTextView>
```

**src/MainActivity.java**

```
private AutoCompleteTextView actv;
actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1); 

String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_of_countries);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
   (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,countries);
actv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, dude...... :)

Comment: please mark this as accepted answer so its easy for everyone.

Comment: How I can mark this as an accepted answer.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235